# Bash Generate a random number between a positive and a negative

Tags: linux, bash, random, between

I have to write a Program, which shows some words on an image which are randomly rotated. I would like these to be between e.g -30 and 30 ° .  But I didn't found any command in bash/UNIX, that could generate a random number between a positive and a negative.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `$RANDOM` will return a random positive number. Use `%61` to get it into the range 0 to 60, then subtract 30.

Comment: This is just simple arithmetic. If you graduated high school it should be obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct approach (no external processes are spawned) was already presented by @Barmar in a comment.

Should the OP need it unraveled, here it is:

```
angle=$(($RANDOM%61-30))
```

but I'd like to suggest a worse alternative, as someone said "Worse is better"

```
angle=$(seq -30 30 | shuf -n 1)
```

- `seq` puts to `stdout` a sequence of integers, newline separated,
- `shuf` shuffles randomly its input,

  - the `-n 1` option means output just the first *randomly shuffled* line,

so that we have that we generate a deck of cards, numbered `-30` … `+30`, we shuffle the deck and we deal just the 1st card.

What I like in my answer is that the range of the solution is stated more clearly, at least from the POV of a non mathematically endowed person.

On the contrary it is SLOWER than using `$RANDOM`

```
10:31 boffi@debian:~ $ time for i in {1..10000} ; do echo > /dev/null ; done

real    0m0.077s
user    0m0.036s
sys     0m0.040s
10:32 boffi@debian:~ $ time for i in {1..10000} ; do echo $(($RANDOM%61-30)) > /dev/null ; done

real    0m0.138s
user    0m0.116s
sys     0m0.020s
10:32 boffi@debian:~ $ time for i in {1..10000} ; do echo $(seq -30 30|shuf -n 1) > /dev/null ; done

real    0m33.328s
user    0m0.372s
sys     0m4.560s
10:33 boffi@debian:~ $
```

(on the other hand, it takes just 3.3 ms, if you use it ONCE in your script… :-)

Comment: Another variant - generate your list once as an array, `angles=($(seq -30 30))`, then you can draw without replacement as many times as you like with `${angles[$(($RANDOM%${#angles[*]}))]}`.  For me the time taken was about as much as for your first two examples added together: I got 0.039s, 0.065s, 13.395s "real" times for yours, and 0.098s for mine.

Comment: What we both are doing is sampling [with replacement](https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/repl.htm);

Comment: Er, yes - I should check that what I type matches what I think!  I did mean to say *"with replacement"*!

Comment: And `angles=({-30..30})` would be simpler, more efficient and more bash-idiomatic.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a snippet that gives random integers between -30 and 30:

```
while true ; do echo $((RANDOM % 61 - 30)) ; done
```

More generally, to get random integers in range [a..b], try:

```
read a b
while true ; do echo $((RANDOM % (b-a+1) + a)) ; done
```

Answer (score 2):

Or generate a random number in a range, which can be positive or negative,  on follow way:

```
getRand(){
    min="${1:-1}"   ## min is the first parameter, or 1 if no parameter is given           
    max="${2:-100}" ## max is the second parameter, or 100 if no parameter is given
    rnd_count=$((RANDOM%(max-min+1)+min)); #
    echo "$rnd_count"
}

var=$(getRand -10 123)
echo $var
```

For bigger range and more random random, replace the RANDOM by SRANDOM. For this you need to update your terminal to version 5.1 at minimum, which is available since end of year 2020.